# d3.js subselection can not retrieve the input value text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, select

Why `d3.js` subselection can not retrieve the input value text? And what is a workaround here?

**Issue example.**

> When you click the button `Click btnT` the resulting text becomes equal to the input value. When you click the button `Click btnS` the resulting text becomes empty, while I would expect the same effect as when clicking the button `Click btnT`.

html

```
<div id="outerDiv">
  <input id="divToTest" />
</div>

<button id="btnT">
Click btnT
</button>

<button id="btnS">
Click btnS
</button>

<div id="resultingText">
  resulting text
</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

js

```
const resultingText = d3.select("#resultingText");

const btnT = d3.select("#btnT");
btnT
  .on("mousedown", function() {
    resultingText.text(d3.select("#divToTest").node().value);
  });

const btnS = d3.select("#btnS");
btnS
  .on("mousedown", function() {
    resultingText.text(d3.select("#outerDiv").select("#divToTest").value);
  });
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/508/)

I would like to be able to retrieve the value from the input using subselection as well as ordinary d3 selection. While the latter works the former does not work.

Comment: You used `selection.node().value` in the first approach, but you try `selection.value` in the second, you still need to access the node:  `d3.select("#outerDiv").select("#divToTest").value` should be `d3.select("#outerDiv").select("#divToTest").node().value`. Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1snozq6a/).

Comment: @AndrewReid Why use an `id` selector twice?

Comment: Why not add a class to the buttons and select by this class because both handlers are identical.

Comment: @rioV8, it could be a minimal example reproduced from some other code that doesn't use IDs, I just read the question as asking why behavior appears to be different for nested/sub selections as compared against un-nested. Though those are good points if working with IDs or to use classes if multiple creating buttons with the same action

Comment: I prefer to use subselections in order to speed up selections (there are a lot of them) which will be performed for the elements inside the parent element and in order to avoid the accidental selection of the element outside of the parent element.

Comment: @iloveseven, also a good point. Did the inclusion of `.node()` solve the issue or could it be something else?

Comment: @AndrewReid, the inclusion of `.node()` did solve the problem.